# Will sass include empty style blocks in its compiled output?

Tags: css, performance, sass, gulp-sass

I sometimes ask my team to leave empty style blocks in place in their sass files that match the structure of the markup so that other developers do not have to spend time recreating this scaffolding structure for markup that they did not write whenever a component has not yet been finalized. It also keeps the structure consistent from one breakpoint to another avoiding any specificity issues with tablet overwriting mobile-first styles. Then they can quickly and easily add styles in their place wherever necessary. If we do not remove these empty blocks when a component is complete, will sass include them in its compiled and minified output?

```
.new-header-main-content {

    .header-inner-content {

        .left-column {

            a {
                img {
                }
            }
        }

        .right-column {


            .desktop-hamburger-menu {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something over complicated in my mind - just check the compiled css and you will find out. Tried it just now and the empty classes are not compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't included in the compiled `css` file. This code would output nothing in the CSS file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can check it using https://www.sassmeister.com.
Actually, it's not good option write smth that it's not used at this moment, follow KISS principle. So, in your example compiled CSS will be empty.